# How do I send a variable value from my form to another page using the POST method?

Tags: 8, forms

In the first page I have the following code:

```
$form['message1'] = array(
  '#markup' => $this->t('Check Your Details once again !!'),
);

$form['candidate_name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Candidate Name:'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['Back'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Back'),
);


$form['submit']= array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Proceed To Pay'),
);

return $form;


function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
  drupal_set_message($this->t('@candidate_name! Wow! Nice choice! Thanks for telling us!', array('@candidate_name' => $form_state->getValue('candidate_name'))));
  $form_state->setRedirect('second_page');
}
```

In the second page I have the following code:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Candidate Name:'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['Back'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Back'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

How can I get the first page candidate name into the second page candidate textfield?

Comment: I'm, starting to think that is not possible to send the form using the POST method in Drupal. Nobody talk about this in the answers :-(

Comment: You want to build a multistep form, so may have a look on [How to Build Multi-step Forms in Drupal 8](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-multi-step-forms-in-drupal-8/) There will be values from the first form used in the second form.

Comment: Check my second edit that have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a pickle! Here are some suggestions:

**Solution 1: Session to the rescue!**

- After the first form is submitted, validated and processed, store the relevant values (the ones you want to pass to the second form) in the session.
- While building the second form, use the values stored in session as default values to pre-populate it.

**Solution 2: Multi-step form**

- Merge the 2 forms into one giant form. Put the elements of the first form in one *container* and the elements of the second form in another *container*. Set `#access` to `FALSE` for the second container to hide the second container.
- After the user submits the info in the first part of the form, hide the first container and show the second one!

**Reference:** See the form examples provided in the [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples).

**Solution 3: Form states?**

Depending on situation, you can also consider using [form states](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states). If you use form states, the hiding and showing can be done in the client-side. So the form will make one request to the server once it has all the data.

**Solution 4: Change form action!**

Depending on situation, you may even consider changing the `action` attribute of the form so that the values are submitted to the URL you specify in the form's `action` attribute.

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty because I think that you have the most complete answer but, I'm continuous figuring out how to send through POST a form to another page. This is very simple using HTML and PHP but in Drupal 8 I can't find how to do this!

Comment: Since you say it is simple in HTML, I wonder if you mean to do something as simple as changing the form's _action_ attribute? Do you want to do something like that?

Comment: Send from a drupal form (in page1) with method=post the information to another page (page2) through POST. In my answer I show how to do this but using a redirect so at the end in page2 you need to use GET and see the values in the url. I don't know if this is posible with the new use of the FORMS in Drupal 8. I don't know if you get the point?

Comment: do you know how to do this?

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions I suggested in the answer?

Comment: In my scenario solution 1 works fine, solution 4 will works. For solution I need to do this with javascript? I don't know how to do this in the Form class.

Comment: But there was nothing mentioned about JS in your question :( I think the question is lacking details in that case. The solutions I recommended do not require JS. If you want to rely on JS, you can make use of Form States and custom scripts. **See:** Solution 3.

Comment: I don't need js, based in solution 4, how can I change the form action in my Form class?

Comment: I think you should be able to do that in your `buildForm()` method? By setting `$form['#action']`. But I've never seen it in action. Try reading documentation or feel free to experiment. Try googling for something like _Drupal change form action_.

Comment: It seems that the correct way to do this is using the PrivateTempStore check the second edit in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I send information from one form to another.

In the first page:

```
use \Drupal\Core\Url;

function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
  drupal_set_message($this->t('@candidate_name! Wow! Nice choice! Thanks for telling us!', array('@candidate_name' => $form_state->getValue('candidate_name'))));

  $params['query'] = [
    'candidate_name' => $form_state->getValue('candidate_name'),
  ];

  $form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromUri('internal:' . 'second_page', $params));
}
```

In the second page:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {   
  $candidate_name = \Drupal::request()->query->get('candidate_name');

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Candidate Name:'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#value' => $candidate_name,
  );

  return $form;
}
```

**EDIT:** For POST method I never see it before, but you can create in the first page a session var and use this var in the second var after the redirection. [Take a look in Storing Session Data with Drupal 8](https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/storing-session-data-drupal-8).

**SECOND EDIT**: It seems that the correct way todo this is with [PrivateTempStore](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21PrivateTempStore.php/class/PrivateTempStore/8.4.x), if you go to see the [CommentAdminOverview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Form%21CommentAdminOverview.php/8.4.x) in Core you will see this:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      ...
      $info = [];
      /** @var \Drupal\comment\CommentInterface $comment */
      foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        $langcode = $comment->language()->getId();
        $info[$comment->id()][$langcode] = $langcode;
      }
      $this->tempStoreFactory
        ->get('comment_multiple_delete_confirm')
        ->set($this->currentUser()->id(), $info);
      $form_state->setRedirect('comment.multiple_delete_confirm');
    }
  }
```

In this page you collect the comment id that you want to delete and made a redirect, and the comment deletion happens in `comment.multiple_delete_confirm` ([ConfirmDeleteMultiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Form%21ConfirmDeleteMultiple.php/function/ConfirmDeleteMultiple%3A%3AgetFormId/8.4.x)) that have the following code:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->commentInfo = $this->tempStoreFactory->get('comment_multiple_delete_confirm')->get($this->currentUser()->id());
    if (empty($this->commentInfo)) {
      return $this->redirect('comment.admin');
    }
    /** @var \Drupal\comment\CommentInterface[] $comments */
    $comments = $this->commentStorage->loadMultiple(array_keys($this->commentInfo));
  ...
  }
```

So, we don't have a POST method from one form to another in Drupal 8 but this can be solved in this way.

Comment: This is pretty much what I posted above, no?

Comment: @Kevin Yes I see now that is very similar. Do you consider that I should delete my answer? I don't have problems doing this.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Thanks Its work well ,!! I need to send the variable as POST method ,How can i achieve this ?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer We have to use /path in Url $form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromUri('internal:' . '/second_page', $params));

Comment: @vijoy I come from update my answer.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I am developing custom module to pass the arguments to WORLDLINE payment gateway ,how  can i send my parameter as POST to gateway ?

Comment: @vijoy at this time I don't know, but I'll made some research to see if I find the answer. If I don't find anything I'll start a bounty here in your question.

Comment: @vijoy Hey could you please update your original question and incorporate that crucial piece of information about the POST to a payment gateway?

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is to add a query string with the value on it with [setRedirect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.2.x).

```
$form_state->setRedirect('second_page', ['name' => $form_state->getValue('name')]);
```

Then, read it in the next form:

```
// top of file
use Drupal\Core\Component\Utility\Xss;

$name = Xss::filter(\Drupal::request()->get('name'));

$form['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Candidate Name:'),
  '#default_value' => isset($name) ? $name : '',
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Note, I wouldn't do this for more sensitive information like credit card numbers or anything like that.

Comment: For sensitive info you could use config, which is the the equivalent of D7's variable_get and variable_set. [Here is a nice tutorial](http://zoubi.me/blog/variable-get-and-variable-set-drupal-8) and make sure mysettingname is unique for each user, like a session ID.

Comment: Yeah it really depends, especially if you're talking PCI complicate for cards, you really can't store that stuff anywhere, only in the transaction service.

Comment: that's very true.

Comment: thank you NO Sssweat, i want to get some arguments from one page and post those values in payment gateway (Worldline), how i can do this..?

Comment: @NoSssweat I would not use `variable_set()` or the Drupal 8 equivalent for a value that is required for a single user. `variable_set()` is global for every user, which means every time a new user fills the form, the new value is set for every _old_ user.

Comment: @Kevin I am trying to get variable from my config how can i get variable in my form

Comment: @kiamlaluno great point, which is why I mentioned that you would need to give the `set()` a unique name, like a session ID or perhaps username if the form is only for authenticated users.

Comment: @NoSssweat But every time `variable_set()` is used, the cache of the variables is cleared, causing the successive calls to `variable_get()` to read from the database. That is why is suggested not to use those functions for values that are only for a single user.

Comment: @kiamlaluno `:O` I didn't know that! thx.

Comment: It seems that the correct way to do this is using the PrivateTempStore check the second edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From 8.2 you can use [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_prepare_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_prepare_form/8.2.x)

E.G.

```
function hook_ENTITY_TYPE_prepare_form(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, $operation, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if ($operation == 'edit') {
    $entity->label->value = 'Altered label';
  }
}
```

So assuming your second form is a node, you could do:

```
function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
  drupal_set_message($this->t('@candidate_name! Wow! Nice choice! Thanks for telling us!', array('@candidate_name' => $form_state->getValue('candidate_name'))));

  $params['query'] = [
'candidate_name' => $form_state->getValue('candidate_name'),
  ];

  $form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromUri('internal:' . 'second_page', $params));
}

function my_modules_node_prepare_form(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, $operation, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $candidate_name = \Drupal::request()->query()->get('candidate_name');
  if($candidate_name) {
    $entity->set('name', $candidate_name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the information in session if it is related to single user.
Hope it helps.